# How secure is the Thrift-Finagle API compared to the Http API and how do they perform?

Tags: java, twitter, thrift, playframework-2.3, finagle

I am using `Thrift-Finagle` for production where by the `AngularJs` web client is connecting to the `Thrift-Finagle API`.

My questions are:

- How secure can this be as compared to http?
- Secondly, how many threads can it handle as compared to http servers?
- Thirdly, does it handle the incoming threads as it uses promises to run the entire back end processing?

Please help me understand this concern of mine. Its really bothering me to know more about its use in production.